# Provide own script when using plugin application in Gradle 1.0

Tags: gradle

I build my project using Gradle 1.0 and I want to use the `application` plugin to create an application distribution package.

Instead of the generated start scripts I want to provide my own.

How can I skip the CreateStartScripts task?

Comment: Maybe I ask why you are not happy with the scripts that get generated? Do you just want to modify/extend them?

Comment: 1. I have more than one start script for platform.
2. Yes, I want to change start script (license header, parameters, stream redirection)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears to be hard-coded, so I am guessing there is no easy way to override it. Maybe  hacking the read-only `startScripts.outputs` property will work.

Either way, I would recommend you just create your own archive task. Here is one that does pretty much exactly what `distZip` does, but without the `startScripts` (borrowed from [ApplicationPlugin.groovy](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/ApplicationPlugin.groovy)).

```groovy
task myDist(type: Zip){
  def baseDir = { archiveName - ".zip" }
  into(baseDir){
    from(project.file("src/dist"))
    into("lib") {
        from(jar)
        from(project.configurations.runtime)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sample code. It works perfect. I have only change name of archive. Thanks