# Why does Gradle configurations.runtime.collect pull in Groovy?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, jar, classpath

why does the `Class-Path` include Groovy, and why is it packaged as if it's a run-time dependency?  What is pulling Groovy in?

```
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/hello_client$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/hello_client$ gradle clean assemble
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
hello_api-dev.jar groovy-all-2.4.1.jar
:startScripts
:distTar
:distZip
:assemble

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.401 secs
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/hello_client$
```

The Groovy JAR's are included in the distribution as well:

```
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/hello_client$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/hello_client$ unzip build/distributions/hello_client-dev.zip 
Archive:  build/distributions/hello_client-dev.zip
   creating: hello_client-dev/
   creating: hello_client-dev/lib/
  inflating: hello_client-dev/lib/hello_client-dev.jar  
  inflating: hello_client-dev/lib/hello_api-dev.jar  
  inflating: hello_client-dev/lib/groovy-all-2.4.1.jar  
   creating: hello_client-dev/bin/
  inflating: hello_client-dev/bin/hello_client.bat  
  inflating: hello_client-dev/bin/hello_client  
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/hello_client$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/hello_client$ java -jar hello_client-dev/lib/hello_client-dev.jar 
hello [fred]
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/hello_client$
```

The `build.groovy` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'maven'

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.mordor.hello.client.HelloClient'
version = 'dev'
group = 'com.some.project'
description = 'hello world KISS'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
if (!hasProperty(mainClassName)) {
    ext.mainClass = mainClassName
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
    compile 'com.github.THUFIR:hello_api:dev'
}

jar.doFirst
{
    def manifestClasspath = configurations.runtime.collect { it.name }
    manifestClasspath = manifestClasspath.unique().join(" ")
    println (manifestClasspath)
    manifest.attributes.put("Main-Class", mainClassName)
    manifest.attributes.put("Class-Path", manifestClasspath)
}
```

I *think* that the solution lies in dealing with `configurations.runtime.collect` in that Groovy should be removed from that collection.  It just seems odd that it's included implicitly.  Is this typical, to include Groovy?

The notion of a `providedCompile` [looks interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982395/how-to-exclude-files-from-distzip-using-gradle), but I'm not sure that it applies.  Am I using Gradle in an odd way somehow?

The [library](https://github.com/THUFIR/hello_api) and [client](https://github.com/THUFIR/hello_client) repos are on github.  Code posted might not be 100% as the latest commits, to make the questions as clear as possible.

Comment: It is likely coming in as a transitive dependency from your compile dependency. Can you show the build.gradle for hello_api?

Comment: client build is here:  https://github.com/THUFIR/hello_api   but that's an interesting line of thought.  I'll take a look!  Yes, you are correct, it's right there in hello_api.   I'll fix that, thanks :)